# "I suppose you don't have" vs "I don't suppose you have"

Tags: negation, negative-raising

Is there any difference in meaning or tone between these two and are they even both valid to begin with:

> I suppose you don't have the keys with you?
> I don't suppose you have the keys with you?

Comment: The first would usually be used in a disparaging tone to indicate "you's" failure. The second is usually said in a hopeful tone and optimistically expects the answer "Yes, I do."

Comment: Many British people phrase questions indirectly to be polite, so instead of saying (e.g. in a shop) 'Do you stock XYZ?', they'll say 'I don't suppose you stock XYZ?', or, to a colleague,  'I don't suppose you've finished that report yet?'. There may be an implication of 'I won't be angry if the answer is "no"'.

Answer (score 0):

They are both valid, though I would be more likely to use the second one. Both are often used in the hope that you do actually have the keys. Logically, if I was supposing nothing at all about the keys, I could use the second but not the first, and so the first sounds more pessimistic to me. In practice though they are often pretty much interchangeable.

Comment: I'd argue that the first version is making a stronger statement - the speaker is expressing the belief that the person addressed does not have the keys.

Comment: @user888379, indeed. As the first is true less often than the second it is a stronger statement.